# Tomcat is not running in Xampp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, xampp

My Tomcat is not running in XAMPP. Anyone can help and solve the problem!

[image: tomcat on xampp]

Comment: `Tomcat` and `Apache` (that stands for the A of XAMPP) are 2 different Web servers, so your question seems to be pointless :/
And since you added `java` and `jsp`. I think you'll need a Tomcat to run your projects

Comment: as the error says. did you install jdk or jre and required ports(8080) are free?

Comment: Tomcat is a java server and does not run under XAMPP. If you have tomcat installed, it will have its own method (depending on your OS) to start/stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp or Lamp is mean is the apache with php5 server. How come tomcat works with this?

To Access tomcat server via apache2 its possible by configuring the virtual hosts. More Details [At Apache vhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)